# How do I start Ubuntu on lock screen?

Tags: 20.04, gnome

So as soon I boot my Ubuntu this screen shows up:

[image]

But the thing is, I only have one user anyway, I'd like to boot directly on "lock screen", it's the screen you get when you use the option "lock", it sends you to a screen to just type your password and hit `enter`, instead of choose the user:

[image]

Is there any way to do it?

It's similar to KDE feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do *exactly* this. Consider the run-time contexts: 1) Awaiting login by any user, no full GUI started yet, no user initialization; and 2) logged in as `$USER`, GUI started, user initialization done. But, there's a partial solution.

Create a `swap` file as big as your RAM, add it to your `/etc/fstab`, and, rather than shutting down Ubuntu, you can "hibernate". When you "resume", you will see the lock screen, with your session behind it. You WILL have to login the hard way once, to perform the initial hibernation.

Read `man mkswap fallocate swapon fstab free pm-action`

Be careful with the vocabulary here, there are 3 separate concepts:

- Hibernate - system state saved to disk, system powers OFF.
- Suspend - system state saved in RAM, system enters low power state.
- Sleep - Processes give up access to CPU for a short time. No effect on system.